# Show, in general cases, that 2 matrices A and B are compatible under the multiplications both ways AB and BA, then AB and BA are both square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Show, in general cases, that 2 matrices A and B are compatible under the
multiplications both ways AB and BA, then AB and BA are both square matrices.

so to show this... am i supposed to just find a random example where AB will be equal to BA then point out that they are both square? how can I find a good example immediately?

Comment: Just look at the dimensions of $A,B,AB,BA$.

Comment: you can multiply the row by the column but not the column by the row. ^^^

Answer (score 0):

We note that by the general formula for matrix multiplication:

$$(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{ik}B_{kj}$$

We note that if we have two matrices: $\mathbf{A}\in K^{n \times m}$ and $\mathbf{B}\in K^{m \times n}$, where $K$ is an arbitrary field, then we have that:

$$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B} \in K^{n \times n} \land \mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}\in K^{m \times m}$$

Else $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}$ is undefined or $\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}$ is undefined. Therefore we can see that if both multiplications are defined then we have that $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}$ are square.